# Why can't we do a Fourier transform of Einstein-Hilbert action?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, fourier-transform, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In QFT, going to the momentum space to extract the propagators and the vertices is a standard procedure. However, the same is not true for the Einstein-Hilbert action. I want to know the precise mathematical reason as to why there is no "momentum space" in case of gravity?

Comment: Technically you CAN do such a transform, but which transform you use would depend upon the topology of the spacetime. If it's flat asymptotically minkowskian a fourier transform will work, if it's another, more complicated topology, you *may* be able to use a generalization of the fourier transform. Look up the Peter-Weyl theorem to learn about this. Also see plancharels theorem. Note you're doing the transform *on* the spacetime itself or the metric tensor

Comment: That's not true. You can find the graviton propagator (in momentum space) from the Einstein-Hilbert action. This was done many decades ago.

Comment: @user44690 Try here - https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.00319

Comment: @Avantgarde    Isn't that all of that in the weak-field approximation of GR, which itself implies a flat spacetime topology ? My understanding was that such approximations fail to capture spacetime solitions and dynamics such as black hole mergers that we're already measuring.  Which is essentially the nonlinear "meat" of General Relativity.

Comment: It is more than just weak-field - it's valid to around the Planck scale, at which the EFT breaks down. The propagator is just the quadratic part of the Lagrangian, while the non-linear terms encode the interactions. You can expand the action around a curved background as well. In modern times, people use amplitudes to compute GR observables (https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.04920). Perhaps there are approaches to compute the propagator non-perturbatively, but that is supposedly hard in the absence of any fixed background..

Comment: @Avantgarde    I get that you can expand the action around a curved spacetime. for example a spatial three-sphere, in which case the expansions are matrix coefficients of SU(2) so-called ultraspherical harmonics (which follows from the Peter-Weyl theorem mentioned in my comment above). In such nice cases of compact spacetimes, one *can* indeed to non-perturbative techniques, but still...we lose any information related to changing topology. Which Hawking, among others, has shown to be itself quantized in a natural way. see Gibbons Hawking: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/gibhaw2.pdf